# How to make JSDoc recognize anonymous function assigned to object property? (example code included)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have a file called `example.js` containing the following content. When I run

```
jsdoc example.js
```

I get an `./out` folder as expected but the resulting documentation does not contain `foo.greeting`, only `greeting`.

```js
const foo = {};

/**
 * greets with name in text
 * @param {string} name  - name
 * @returns {string} - an IPC response object
 */
foo.greeting = (name) => {
  return 'hello, ' + name;
};

/**
 * greets with name in text
 * @param {string} name  - name
 * @returns {string} - an IPC response object
 */
const greeting = (name) => {
  return 'hello, ' + name;
};
```

Is it possible to make jsdoc recognize the anonymous function assignment to the object property?

I am currently using JSDoc 3.6.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by tagging it with [`@function`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-function.html):

```
/**
 * @function greeting
 * @description greets with name in text
 * @param {string} name  - name
 * @returns {string} - an IPC response object
 */
foo.greeting = (name) => {
  return 'hello, ' + name;
};
```

Whether this produces exactly what you're looking for, it's hard to say, but it does at least produce *something*.

Comment: This is sufficient for me. Thank you. Meanwhile I also found out that one can use \@namespace and \@memberof.